# javascript function values to be stored in a cookie

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeStyle(title) {
var lnks = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
for (var i = lnks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
if (lnks[i].getAttribute('rel').indexOf('style')> -1 && lnks[i].getAttribute('title')) {
lnks[i].disabled = true;
if (lnks[i].getAttribute('title') == title) lnks[i].disabled = false;
}}}
function getActiveStyleSheet() {
var i, a;
 for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")); i++) {
  if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
  && a.getAttribute("title")
  && !a.disabled) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
} 
</script>
```

I have the above code, i need help with how i would use the getActiveStyleSheet function to store in a cookie or in html5 localstorage that i could call in each window to show the users style preference.  I really don't have a clue how i would implement this if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set some data in localStorage like so:

`localStorage.setItem(key, value)`

If you want to store the results of your `getActiveStyleSheet` call in localStorage you could do that like this:

```
// set the active stylesheet in localstorage
localStorage.setItem('activeStylesheet', getActiveStyleSheet())

// retrieve the data from localStorage
localStorage.getItem('activeStylesheet')
```

You could do something similar with cookies. Here is some documentation on how to write cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie#Writing_a_cookie

And some further reading on localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#localStorage

Comment: Thanks Freyday - i tried something similiar before but it still doesn't work.  I'm calling the localStorage.getItem('activestylesheet') in the head of my document in between <script> tags, is this correct??

Comment: Looks about right. Have you verified that your browser supports localStorage? Here's a good article on detecting localStorage: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/localstorage-pattern
You can fallback to cookies if localStorage is not available.

Comment: Also, the localStorage key is case-sensitive so `localStorage.getItem('foo')` is not the same as `localStorage.getItem('fOo')`

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle that demonstrates it a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/mikefrey/bZZTe/2/

Comment: thanks for all your help, im probably going to have to abandon it to be honest, i dont really understand why it wouldnt work and my assignment deadline is tomorrow, but thanks anyway :)